# Adding a new line to a text file after 5 occurrences of a comma in Bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a text file that is basically one giant excel file on one line in a text file. An example would be like this:

```
Name,Age,Year,Michael,27,2018,Carl,19,2018
```

I need to change the third occurance of a comma into a new line so that I get

```
Name,Age,Year 
Michael,27,2018 
Carl,19,2018
```

Please let me know if that is too ambiguous and as always thank you in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

With Gnu sed:

```
sed -E 's/(([^,]*,){2}[^,]*),/\1\n/g'
```

To change the number of fields per line, change `{2}` to one less than the number of fields. For example, to change every fifth comma (as in the *title* of your question), you would use:

```
sed -E 's/(([^,]*,){4}[^,]*),/\1\n/g'
```

In the regular expression, `[^,]*,` is "zero or more characters other than `,` followed by a `,`; in other words, it is a single comma-delimited field. This won't work if the fields are quoted strings with internal commas or newlines.

Regardless of what Linux's `man sed` says, the `-E` flag is an extension to Posix sed, which causes sed to use extended regular expressions (EREs) rather than basic regular expressions (see `man 7 regex`). `-E` also works on BSD sed, used by default on Mac OS X. (Thanks to @EdMorton for the note.)

Comment: @EdMorton: OK, changed. My fingers still want to type sed -r, though. :-)

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='[,\n]' '{ORS=(NR%3 ? "," : "\n")} 1' file
Name,Age,Year
Michael,27,2018
Carl,19,2018
```

With any awk:

```
$ awk -v RS=',' '{sub(/\n$/,""); ORS=(NR%3 ? "," : "\n")} 1' file
Name,Age,Year
Michael,27,2018
Carl,19,2018
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**:

```
$ cat /tmp/22.txt
Name,Age,Year,Michael,27,2018,Carl,19,2018,Nooka,35,1945,Name1,11,19811

$ echo "Name,Age,Year"; grep -o "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*,[1-9][0-9]*,[1-9][0-9]\{3\}" /tmp/22.txt
Michael,27,2018
Carl,19,2018
Nooka,35,1945
Name1,11,1981
```

Or, `,[1-9][0-9]\{3\}` if you don't want to put `[0-9]` 3 more times for the YYYY part.

**PS**: This solution will give you only YYYY for the year (even if the data for YYYY is `19811` (typo mistakes if any), you'll still get `1981`

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for 3 fragments, each without a comma and separated by a comma.
The last fields can give problems (not ending with a comma and mayby only two fields.
The next command looks fine.

```
grep -Eo "([^,]*[,]{0,1}){0,3}" inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/,/\n/3;P;D' file
```

Replace every third `,` with a newline, print ,delete the first line and repeat.